# C# does the compiler leave re-references in the final binary?

Tags: c#, rider, low-level, decompiler, compiler-specific

I have this code:

```
    private static void Tokenize(RichTextLabel Log,string commandString){
        Log.Text += "\n&";
        int[] tokens = new int[5];
        int current = 0;
        while (current < commandString.Length){
            switch (commandString[current]){
            case ' ':
                Log.Text += "+";
                break;
            default:
                Log.Text += "_";
                break;
            }
            current++;
        }
        Log.Text += "\n";
    }
```

And when i look at the "compiled code" (Low-level C# in rider's IL Viewer) which i know is not perfect or accurate in all cases. But this is what it produces:

```
    private static void Tokenize(RichTextLabel Log, string commandString)
    {
      RichTextLabel richTextLabel1 = Log;
      richTextLabel1.Text = string.Concat(richTextLabel1.Text, "\n&");
      int[] tokens = new int[5];
      for (int current = 0; current < commandString.Length; ++current)
      {
        if (commandString[current] == ' ')
        {
          RichTextLabel richTextLabel2 = Log;
          richTextLabel2.Text = string.Concat(richTextLabel2.Text, "+");
        }
        else
        {
          RichTextLabel richTextLabel3 = Log;
          richTextLabel3.Text = string.Concat(richTextLabel3.Text, "_");
        }
      }
      RichTextLabel richTextLabel4 = Log;
      richTextLabel4.Text = string.Concat(richTextLabel4.Text, "\n");
    }
```

As you can see, it produces 4 repetitive `RichTextLabel richTextLabel = Log;`
My question is, is this accurate? If so why does it need to re-reference the object multiple times?

Comment: It doesn't know what `Log` does, so to prevent the getter and setter referring to different objects, it caches it in a variable. See the C# spec https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#12214-compound-assignment "the operation is evaluated as x = (T)(x «op» y), where T is the type of x, except that x is evaluated only once."

Comment: Log is an field instance of a Class

Comment: OK but maybe another thread changed it etc. Point is: the compiler needs to guarantee that the same object is used in both the getter and setter of the compound assignment, it does that by making a copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mostly an accurate representation of what is going on, except that I think the variable doesn't actually exist.

[The C# spec states:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#12214-compound-assignment)

> **12.21.4 Compound assignment**
>
> An operation of the form `x «op»= y` is processed by applying binary operator overload resolution ([§12.4.5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#1245-binary-operator-overload-resolution)) as if the operation was written `x «op» y`. Then,
>
> - If the return type of the selected operator is implicitly convertible to the type of x, the operation is evaluated as `x = x «op» y`, except that **`x` is evaluated only once** *(my bold)*.
> - Otherwise, ..... the operation is evaluated as `x = (T)(x «op» y)`, where `T` is the type of `x`, except that **`x` is evaluated only once**.

And since the compiler doesn't know what `Log` does, to prevent the getter and setter potentially referring to different objects, it just caches it in a hidden variable.

---

Having said all that, looking at the [generated IL in Sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgJgIwFgBQyDMABGgQMIEDeOB1RhYAdsAQB4UDmApsANwDOX3AL45huQsQAiFKjTIBjdgMEBeAvQ4B3ABQBKbjOr4iAFgIBZXdOw0bBOQDpW8VQFZ91mqMFA===) shows that a `dup` opcode is used, so instead of caching it in a variable, it actually caches it in the stack. So Rider might just be generating a variable in order to represent the same semantics in psueudo-C#. The effect and performance should be the same though, and you shouldn't expect that the compiler will necessarily use one form over the other.

Comment: Even if this has no performance implications. How would one go about not getting these generated? Are they a result of me doing something wrong. Log is just a field instance of a class passed to the Tokenized() method.

Comment: No, like I said it's perfectly normal. I'm really not sure what your issue is.